# How to get JIRA like change history using hibernate envers audit log?

Tags: jira, hibernate-envers

I am trying to show JIRA like change history on UI. I am using `Spring Data JPA` and I have configured audit trail with Envers (v5.3.7). I can get list of all revisions using `AuditQuery`, for a particular entity by its primary key value.

Is there an easy way to calculate "delta" across revisions and identify properties that were changed? (With old and new value)

I have added `@Audited(withModifiedFlag = true)` annotation to my entity class. It adds one more column in the `<entity>_aud` table for each property indicating if the property was changed or not. I am trying to figure out, how to make use of these additional columns.

Comment: There is a new API coming with Envers 6.0 that allows you to use the `withModifiedFlag=true` attribute setup and be able to get a list of revisions for an entity and it will tell you what fields were changed at that revision, so you do not need to use an interceptor or custom tables; just Envers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need something like JIRA you have to build it by your own.

I would suggest that you use Hibernate Interceptors:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#events

As you can see in the following example you get the current and the previous state and can then create the delta and store it in your own changelog table:

```
public static class LoggingInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {
    @Override
    public boolean onFlushDirty(
        Object entity,
        Serializable id,
        Object[] currentState,
        Object[] previousState,
        String[] propertyNames,
        Type[] types) {
            LOGGER.debugv( "Entity {0}#{1} changed from {2} to {3}",
                entity.getClass().getSimpleName(),
                id,
                Arrays.toString( previousState ),
                Arrays.toString( currentState )
            );
            return super.onFlushDirty( entity, id, currentState,
                previousState, propertyNames, types
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Simon for pointing me in the right direction. Instead of using EmptyInterceptor I used org.hibernate.event.spi.PreUpdateEventListener. It worked for me. I am posting my code on this thread.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;

import org.hibernate.event.service.spi.EventListenerRegistry;
import org.hibernate.event.spi.EventType;
import org.hibernate.event.spi.PreUpdateEvent;
import org.hibernate.event.spi.PreUpdateEventListener;
import org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class AuditListener implements PreUpdateEventListener {   
    @Autowired
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        SessionFactoryImpl sessionFactory = entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactoryImpl.class);
        EventListenerRegistry registry = sessionFactory.getServiceRegistry().getService(EventListenerRegistry.class);

        // You can also add listener for a specific entity-type instead of event-group
        // In my case I needed global event listener
        registry.getEventListenerGroup(EventType.PRE_UPDATE).appendListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPreUpdate(PreUpdateEvent event) {
        String[] propertyNames = event.getPersister().getPropertyNames();
        Object[] oldValues = event.getOldState();
        Object[] newValues = event.getState();
        for (int index = 0; index < propertyNames.length; index++) {
            String propertyName = propertyNames[index];
            Object oldValue = oldValues[index];
            Object newValue = newValues[index];

            // This is just sample code
            boolean changed = oldValue != newValue;
            if (changed) {
                System.out.println("Audit log -> Property: " + propertyName + ", Old value: " + oldValue + ", New value: " + newValue);

                // Actual code that persists audit log
                ...
                ...
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: How would you add a listener for a specific entity-type?